# how to kick people in discord C#

Tags: c#, discord

I have some code meant to kick people on discord

```
 namespace bot.Core.Commands
 {
    public class Kick : ModuleBase<SocketCommandContext>
    {
        [Command("kick"), Summary("")]
        public async Task kick(IGuildUser User, string reason = "no reason")
        {
            User.KickAsync(reason);
        }
    }
 }

            int argpos = 0;
        if (!(Message.HasStringPrefix("$", ref argpos) || Message.HasMentionPrefix(Client.CurrentUser, ref argpos))) return;

        var result = await Commandss.ExecuteAsync(context, argpos);
        if(!result.IsSuccess)
        {
            await context.Channel.SendMessageAsync("Command not found or has failed, Commands can also only be ran by an administrator");
        }
```

however it ALWAYS throws Command not found or has failed, Commands can also only be ran by an administrator. can anybody shed some insight as to why?
all other commands work just fine except for this one. thanks in advance

I am using windows on c# vs 2017

also its not the permissions

Comment: Are you using `Discord.Net`?

Comment: yes I am and vs 2017

Answer (score 2):

You need to add `[Remainder]` before the declaration of `reason` in the command parameters.

```
 namespace bot.Core.Commands
 {
    public class Kick : ModuleBase<SocketCommandContext>
    {
        [Command("kick"), Summary("Kicks a user from the guild.")]
        public async Task KickCommand(IGuildUser user, [Remainder] string reason = "no reason")
        {
            user.KickAsync(reason);
        }
    }
 }
```

Otherwise, in a command such as:

```
"$kick @Username Sending NSFW Pics"
```

Everything after "Sending" would be considered as extra parameters and not part of `reason`, so the command would fail since it only accepts two parameters. Adding `[Remainder]` tells the command to look at everything that is typed afterwards as part of the same parameter.

That said, the command should work if you don't specify a reason. Is this true? And have you tried kicking without recording a reason? (Just `user.KickAsync()`)